# I deployed my website on aws s3, the app is running on my domain. I can not reload on other routes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I can not reload my website, if I reload on homepage, it is okay. but I can not reload on other routes.[image]

Comment: Your site doesn't have access to some of the content (CSS?, JS?, images?).  Check your S3 permissions.

Comment: thank for you comment. here is my bucket policy ` {
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
  {
   "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Principal": "*",
   "Action": [
    "s3:PutObject",
    "s3:PutObjectAcl",
    "s3:GetObject"
   ],
   "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::coupon-admin-apps/*"
  }
 ]
}` it still have accessDenied

Comment: Is your `Principal` really an empty string?  [The docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/HostingWebsiteOnS3Setup.html#step4-add-bucket-policy-make-content-public) indicate that it needs to be an `*` character.  And you need a `*` at the end of the `Resource` too.

Answer (score 2):

Configure the error pages in cloudfront: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/custom-error-pages-and-responses-for-amazon-cloudfront/

Set 404 to return index.html with status code 200.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I just set 403, return /index.html with status code 200. it is working now.

Comment: Ahhh - thanks @twharmon - now I understand your answer.  It's yet another dumb ReactJS router issue, correct?  I'd have spent all day going through S3 permissions without this.